# how can I run Javascript on one page, that the user had input on the previous page?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have the Javascript written by the user on one page to be saved and used for the next page. By this, I mean, I need to grab the contents of a div, and somehow save that into a .JS file, which wil automatically run as the next page loads. Is there a way in which I could do this, Or is there another way in which this could be achieved?

Basically, something along the lines of what Codecademy has done, but not live?

Comment: There is a way to do this, but it is a HUGE security hole in your application. Why in the world would you want to do this?  The answer would be to store the div data in, say localStorage and use `eval()` on that value in the second page. But this is HIGHLY ADVISED AGAINST DOING!

Comment: What exactly would be the risks in doing this? I realize someone could potentially append an inappropriate picture on the next page, but JS is entirely client side? The couldn't do anything damaging, could they.

Comment: How do you think viruses are spread over the web? Either the user agrees to download and install an executable program. Or, a hacker exploits a security hole in a browser that gives them access to your entire file system, which can turn your PC into a "bot" under the control of the hacker. This is why you are constantly needing to update your browser, because hackers keep finding holes in them.

Comment: I had planned to have the code deleted instantly after the user ran the code, but I'm using Nicks answer below now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just working on a local project (nothing server side). you could store the value to localStorage.

```
// page 1
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
     <div contentEditable="true" id="i1"></div><button id="b1">open next page</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    var div = document.getElementById('i1'), text = "desired value";
        div.innerText = text;
    document.getElementById('b1').onclick = function(){
      localStorage['div value'] = div.innerText; window.open('page2.html'); window.close('page1.html');
    }
  </script>
</html>

// page 2
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="p"></p>
    <button id="b2">go back</button>
  </body>
  <script>
   p.innerText = localStorage['div value']? localStorage['div value']: "There is no value in your div";
   b2.onclick = function(){ window.open('page1.html'); window.close('page2.html'); }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: The user won't be writing the JS down them selves, however it would be created for them and .append 'ed in to a div. so could I instead use .innerHTML in place of .value when first storing the data? Since there will be no <input>

Comment: Cheers, worked perfectly. All I had to do was give the <script> tags the 'p' ID, and it worked!

Comment: This will just display the code on page "b", not run it. As I said, there really is just one way to do this and it should really never be done - - eval()

Comment: It's runs the code alright. simply give the 'p' ID to a script tag. And it'll be run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to change the architecture, I have a question as your answer. Have you tried single page JS applications through [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/), [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) etc?

Answer (score -2):

you don't need to save into a .JS file

you need to post the JS to the server, then render it to the next page

```
i'm the next page
<script>
    // user's code
</script>
```

Comment: How would I go about posting it to the server? I use WAMP, if that means anything.

Comment: <form method="post" action="your_server_url">
     <textarea name="code">
</form>

maybe you can do it like Scott Marcus said, save to localStorage and `eval()`

Comment: I could use PHP for this, couldn't I? It would just be a lot easier as I have close to no experience with servers!

Comment: you think which one is easier, and just do it.

Comment: Eye... Well, Cheers.

Comment: This is not an answer. It doesn't explain how the data gets from page "a" to page "b".